# Disable Publishing in MSBuild

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I have an application that I wrote in C# and build in VisualStudio.  One day I was exploring the 'publish' tab in the project properties section just to see what it did.  Now everytime I build my application, I get a whole bunch of files related to ClickOnce installers (*.application, *.deploy, etc.) that I don't really want anymore.  How do I disable or otherwise stop these items from appearing when I build my project??

Comment: What kind of application is this one? MVC, Desktop, Vsto?

Comment: its a normal old desktop application.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I solved the problem by unchecking 'Sign ClickOnce Manifests' in the 'Signing' tab as well as 'Enable ClickOnce security settings' in the 'Security' tab.

Comment: Good to know that I'm not the only one going nuts on Visual Studio's behaviours. I did the same thing as you did; Explored the publish setting...

Comment: I tried that but it's not fixing this (2017). Has anything changed since?

Answer (score 10):

For WinForms Windows Application

Go to: Project > Properties > Security

Then uncheck 'Enable ClickOnce security settings'

Comment: It's not sufficient for me.

Answer (score 2):

2 ways to do it,

- Go to the web project and click on properties, go to the 'Package/Publish Web' tab and uncheck the option
- Over ride it from your build definition, click edit on your build defination, go to process tab and expand advanced and pass the following argument **/P:CreatePackageOnPublish=false**

HTH
Cheers, Tarun

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't a web application.

Answer (score -2):

In vs 16.5 go to project=>properties=>package/publish and enable it.

[Web Deployment Overview for Visual Studio and ASP.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dd394698(v=vs.110)?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(WebApplicationProjects.PackagePublishOverview);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.5)%26rd%3Dtrue)